# How to filter by $near in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, geojson

I want to filter using `$near`, but I got this error:

> Command failed [count]:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017",
  "ok" : 0.0 , 
  "errmsg" : "not handled: $maxDistance" , 
  "code" : 2}
```

Here is my code:

```
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .push("geometry")
                    .add("$maxDistance", 500)
                    .push("$near")
                        .push("$geometry")
                            .add("type", "Point")
                            .add("coordinates", array)
                .get();
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
```

This is my data:

[image]

Comment: command failed [count]: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not handled: $maxDistance" , "code" : 2}

Comment: I included the image itself in the question. instead of the reference to it. However, since the image represents text, it would be better to have the text version than the image. Also, I added the error message that was mentioned in the comments.